# Export a Row or Column as an image

Tags: graphics, export

How could I export the following as a single image and set its dimensions ?

```
Column[{Row[{Graphics@Disk[], Graphics@Rectangle[]}],
        Row[{Graphics@Rectangle[], Graphics@Disk[]}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd do this, probably

```
Export[
 "~/Desktop/out.png",
 GraphicsGrid[
  {
   {Graphics@Disk[], Graphics@Rectangle[]}, {Graphics@Rectangle[], 
    Graphics@Disk[]}
   },
  ImageSize -> 800
  ]
 ]
```